# CSS Vertical Align Objects in Col

Tags: css, image

I cannot seem to get this to work and spending too many hours on this.  I am assuming it should be simple.  I am looking for the desired effect of having an image over top of some text and have them both centered horizontally, but ALSO have them vertically centered in the middle.

Any help would be appreciated!

A = a row, B = a column, C = an image, D =

of text

Answer (score 1):

@TO15108, this can be accomplished using a flexbox. To create one, set the `display` property value to `flex`.

From there, you can leverage the `justify-content` and `align-items` properties to get the vertical and horizontal centering you are trying to accomplish.

I've included a code snippet for you to see how this works. Make sure to expand it to it's full size.

```css
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.col {
    flex: 0 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        <div>some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        <div>some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the a table: table cells can be aligned vertically using the "vertical-align:middle" property.

Here is a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rL927hn0/

The page itself is a table:

```
#page {position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;display:table;}
```

The content is placed within the table-cell (the A element in your example):

```
#content {display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;}
```

Each section of the content (the B element in your example) is an inline-block:

```
.square {display:inline-block;}
```

Cheers